# Apache Hadoop Configuration Options

Tags: hadoop

Being a new developer a Hadoop application, I'm struggling to get a grasp of the myriad configuration options for a `Map/Reduce` or a `Oozie` or a  `Sqoop` job. None of the recommended books or sites deal with this comprehensively. Any new tool in Hadoop ecosystem you will see more. I wanted to ask what is the best way/resource to get an understanding of the job configuration options.

Comment: If any answer have solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have all the configurations of Hadoop:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/core-default.xml

Also if you want to see what are your current configuration and where it comes from run this:

```
$ hadoop org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
```

Answer (score 1):

I read hadoop : the definitive guide It was very useful for me.

Moreover while reading any [configuration property in hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/cluster_setup.html#Site+Configuration),you have to associate that with the corresponding element of the hadoop.

Like any property that starts with `mapred.map` is used to set the property of the mapper task same way  `mapred.reduce` is for reducer.

This way you can easily understand and memorize the properties.